# Laptop suddenly using large amounts of data

Tags: windows

Last week I ran the windows updates on my mums laptop as they hadn't been done for quite some time. As she forgets to check them we changed over to automatic updates. Since then she has been using massive amounts of data. She has gone through almost 3.5gb in a week, when she normally only uses 1gb in month! Does anyone know what could be causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: We need more information it sounds like you just downloaded several large updates

Comment: It used 1gb that day doing the updates, but since then has been using large amounts each time she turns the computer on. She is 66 and hardly uses it for anything other than a quick look at Facebook. Yesterday it used over 700mb and can't work out why as it never has before.

Comment: Can you check the Windows Update history to see the list of updates it has downloaded since the day you first installed them. I guess, it could be due to some pretty large updates automatically downloaded (may be a service pack or something) after the initial update had completed.